# Simple Class Function Boolean Output

Tags: javascript, html, class, boolean

I want to make a class function that displays a variable of type boolean. How do I do this? I'm not even sure what I'm doing up to this point.

```
  <body>

   <div class="output"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     var car = "ferrari";
     var garage = 52;

       class blue {

         constructor(fire) {
           if(2>5) {
             getElementsByClass('output').innerHTML = car;
           }
           else {
             getElementsByClass('output').innerHTML = garage;
           }
         }
       }
   </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Neither do we, please explain more clearly what you trying to do and what you have already tried.

Comment: 1 guy did. Please unhold this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` and pass the index `0` since it returns a nodelist.

Secondly invoke `Blue` class using `new` operator. Convention is `class` or constructor function is pascal case

```js
var car = "ferrari";
var garage = 52;

class Blue {
  constructor(fire) {
    if (2 > 5) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].innerHTML = car;
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].innerHTML = garage;
    }
  }

}

let k = new Blue('testFire')
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what you're doing with; let k = new Blue('testFire')